# Need an AppleScript to merge all .CSV files excluding the header record of all but one

Tags: applescript

I've looked for a solution to this and found some cool ways of doing it using the command line. However, I'd like to use AppleScript so I can incorporate it into other scripts down the road. I need to "merge" all .CSV files in a folder into a single .CSV file. The folder will have approximately 10 files (number varies each day) each with a few hundred records.  The headers are the same for each file so I need to keep the first header and remove the header from all others.  Ultimately I'd like to have the output file in the same folder and name it with the name of the first file with a slight modification as follows.
Current file names look like this:  IC-SchoolName YYYY-YBPoseExport.CSV I'd like to replace the SchoolName with something like "Combined"
I'm new to this and don't know where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It’s great to continue your journey learning new solutions with one language,  but since apple script can call out to a shell script, you can still be portable if someone solves this with a shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
to mergeCSVFiles at path as «class furl»
        local path, tmp
        
        set (path) to path as text
        get the path & "newfile.tmp"
        set tmp to the result's POSIX path
        
        close access (open for access tmp)
        set eof of tmp to 0
        
        set my text item delimiters to {linefeed, "IC-", space}
        
        tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents"
                tell (the folder path's files whose name extension = "csv")
                        get the first file's POSIX path
                        read the result using delimiter linefeed
                        write "" & result & linefeed to tmp as "utf8"
                        
                        repeat with f in rest of (get POSIX path of files)
                                read f using delimiter linefeed
                                write (rest of result as text) & linefeed ¬
                                        to tmp as "utf8" starting at eof
                        end repeat
                        
                        set suffix to the last text item of (get some file's name)
                end tell
                
                set ICCombined to "IC-Combined" & space & the suffix
                set the name of file tmp to ICCombined
                get the path of file ICCombined in the folder path
        end tell
        
        tell application id "com.apple.finder" to activate (reveal the result)
end mergeCSVFiles
```

This handler can be passed an absolute (full) file path to the folder containing the `.csv` files to be merged.  Initially, a blank file is created named `"newfile.tmp"`, into which the full contents of the first `.csv` file is written.  The remaining `.csv` files are read in their entirety, and appended to `"newfile.tmp"` with the exception of their first lines (their headers).

Once the merge is complete, `"newfile.tmp"` is renamed to `"IC-Combined <suffix>.csv"`, where `<suffix>` is obtained from one of the other `.csv` filenames and taken to be everything that appears after, but not including, the first space character.  If your example file name included the literal suffix, then the resulting file will be named `"IC-Combined YYYY-YBPoseExport.CSV"` (although you really should keep your file extensions lowercase, otherwise it can be problematic in application (including the shell) that enumerates files and performs searches on file names on a case-sensitive basis, which is pretty standard on UNIX-like systems).

Finally, the file is revealed in *Finder*, which will coincide with its renaming.

To invoke the handler, here's an example:

```
mergeCSVFiles at "/Users/CK/Documents/Some Folder"
```

It returns no value.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I added a property with path to desktop and an alias for the input folder.  Then set the input folder by prompting the user to select the input folder.  Thank you so much, not only does this work but it helps me understand handlers better.

Comment: I anticipated that some customisation towards getting the input folder would be needed, and made the handler able to cope with any type of path or file reference that it's passed. This includes plain text posix (slash notation) or HFS (colon-delimited) paths; aliases; POSIX files: and it should also be okay with System Events and Finder folder references. Good lessons to learn about plain text files are that when writing, always put a single empty line at the end; and when reading, if lines need splitting, use the `read` to do this during reading rather than doing it yourself after it's read.